# Recursion factorial code c# - "Invalid token" error

Tags: c#, recursion, factorial

I am attempting to write a recursion code that computes the factorial from a given number. (Factorial of 3 is "3*2*1 = 6"). I have written the following code, and the following error message is printed

**"Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration"**

I have checked my code and in my eyes, I can't see an error, is there anything I can do to fix the issue? The c# code is posted below.
(ps. I'm not a c# wizz.)

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num1;
            int num2;
            int num3 = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Insert number");
            num1 = Console.ReadLine();

            num2 = num1 -1;

            factorial(num1, num2, num3);

            Console.WriteLine("Your number is {0}", factorial());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();


        static int factorial(int a, int b, int c)
        {
            if (a > 0)
            {
                a * b = c;
                factorial(a - 1, c, c);
                return c;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code, and it does not compile, lets go through each error

> Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

This, as pointed out in the other answers is the `Console.Readkey()` in the middle of your class outside of any method. Move it into the bottom of the `Main` method.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'

This is due to the line `num1 = Console.ReadLine();` as that method returns a string and you're trying to assign it to an int. The *right* way to deal with this is to check the user input, to ensure they have typed a number. For brevity I'll do it the *wrong* and just assume its right.

```
num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Use TryParse here, and notify the user if they typed something wrong
```

> No overload for method 'factorial' takes 0 arguments

This is because you've tried to call your `factorial` method with no arguments. I think you were trying to output the result from the call above.

```
var result = factorial(num1, num2, num3);
Console.WriteLine("Your number is {0}", result);
```

> The type or namespace name 'a' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is due to this line: `a * b = c;` which just doesn't make sense. I assume you meant `c = a * b;`

Finally

> 'Rextester.Program.factorial(int, int, int)': not all code paths return a value

You need to return a value outside the `if` of `factorial`. Here you then get into an endless loop, but at least your code compiles! Now just fix your algorithm. This is much simpler

```
static int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n == 1)
        return 1;

    return factorial(n-1) * n;
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/OUCC98161

Answer (score 3):

You have `Console.ReadKey();` outside method declaration. Move it into `public static void Main(string[] args)` and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

It wont like `Console.WriteLine("Your number is {0}", factorial());`

Your factorial function has 3 parameters, you've never declared one with none.

You need to keep the result and display it.

If you are interested, there are also ways to improve the actual factorial routine you've got too

Comment: That's a problem too. I didn't realize that until your answer coming.

Comment: In what way would you improve the routine?

Comment: Normally a factorial function would go int factorial( int value) { return value==2?value*factorial(value-1):value*2;}